# OpenSL ES precise start of playback

Tags: android, opensl

I am working on an Android app that uses OpenSL ES for audio input/output. However, I've been struggling to come up with a solution that would enable to start playback at a precisely given time (e.g. I want to start playing in exactly 3.2 seconds from now on). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by allocating a larger buffer that I am filling with zeros in the beginning according to sample rate. Seems to work well.